# Type for `this` argument in shared function between Classes

Tags: typescript

I am sure this question has already been asked and answered and I simply don't know how to Google it properly. Feel free to copy-paste me the appropriate link.

I am currently implementing a library in TypeScript for my company. Not to disclose too much information, this library basically renders a user interface based on a configuration file.

Since the interface will be rendered in different platforms (mobile, desktop, etc.) every platform is a `Class` in the code.

Different platforms have mostly different implementations **BUT** some functions are shared. The tricky part is that these shared functions are passed the `Class` calling them as an argument, since they then call a static method of that class.

I would like to know:

- How to tell TypeScript the `type` of `responsibleClass`.
- Is there any better naming convention for `responsibleClass`?

```
export function performAction(action: Action, responsibleClass: any) {
  switch (action) {
...
    default:
      responsibleClass.someMethod();
      break;
...
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Gerard

Comment: Use instances of "responsible class" instead of classes with static methods.

Comment: Just wanted to ask, do you want to pass a reference to class constructor or class instance ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass any object with `someMethod` method, you can use this constraint:

```js
type Action = {
  tag: 'action'
}

export function performAction<
  Instance extends { someMethod: () => void }
>(action: Action, responsibleClass: Instance) {
  switch (action) {

    default:
      responsibleClass.someMethod();
      break;
  }
}
```

`Instance` - refers to any object with `someMethod`. Now, ts will allow you to use instance only with `someMethod` method.

You can even pass class with static method `someMethyod`:

```js
type Action = {
  tag: 'action'
}

class Foo {
  static someMethod: () => {}
}

export function performAction<
  Obj extends { someMethod: () => void }
>(action: Action, responsibleClass: Obj) {
  switch (action) {

    default:
      responsibleClass.someMethod();
      break;
  }
}
performAction({ tag: 'action' }, Foo)
```

because TS has structural type system

Answer (score 0):

I've tought of 2 possible solutions for this.

1- You could create a new type that wrap all the instances you want

```
type TResponsibleClass = MobileClass | DesktopClass | OtherClass
```

And use that type on the responsibleClass argument:

```
export function performAction(action: Action, responsibleClass: TResponsibleClass) {
   ...
}
```

2- You could use TS generic types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Basically, this way, you can create a type kind of an argument of the function, so when you use it, you can also pass the type:

```
export function performAction<FutureType>(action: Action, responsibleClass: FutureType){
   ...
}
```

And then invoking the function this way

```
performAction<DesktopClass>(action, DesktopClass);
```

This means that the argument responsibleClass will be of type DesktopClass, so you could pass the type you want.

```
performAction<CustomType>(action, anyClass);
```